# How to authenticate users with webview in android app?

Tags: android, authentication, webview

soo basically I have created a website with all functionality of user authentication  in Django. after this when I created the webview app in Android studio  for the same website authentication is working but its not saving user who has already logged in like we see in our browser.
after terminating the app the authentication is reset and we have to retype credentials  when we terminate the application and reopen's it.

so I basically want to save logged in user authentication even if he terminate the app.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793640/how-to-make-android-webview-remember-username-and-password

Comment: Cookies aren't saved, because WebView purposely doesn't save state between instances.  If you need this, you'll need to save the cookie to disk and restore it from disk yourself.  CookieManager can do this for you, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager